No se visualizan efectos especiales en Firefox
Presento este problema en mi código ya que busco que ocurran efectos especiales al poner el cursor en cada una de las imágenes, por ejemplo, cuando el puntero se pone sobre la imagen de la casa, esta se debe agrandar a un 20% y cuando de pone sobre la imagen de la flecha derecha, esta debe encogerse un 20%, cambiar gradualemnte de imagen a una colorida y, al mismo tiempo, girar 20 grados. Algo parecido para con la imagen de la flecha izquierda (solo que esta no se encoge). La cuestión aqui es que, cuando cargo la página en navegadores como Avast Secure Browser y Google Chrome, esta funciona tal cual como es deseada al poner los punteror sobre ellas, pero con Firefox es distinto, funciona todo bien slvo que el cambio de imagen se hace de forma instantánea (no gradual). ¿Me podrían explicar como arreglar este problema con el navegador Firefox? Este es el codigo de UD2_estilos.css
     div {
    float: left;
 }
 
 #imgIzq, #imgDer {
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    }

#imgIzq, #imgDer, #imgCasa {
    transition: all 1s linear;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

 #imgIzq{
    background-image: url("IMAGENES_ACT1/izq_WB.jpg");
    }
    
#imgIzq:hover{
    background-image: url("IMAGENES_ACT1/izq_redim.jpg");
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);   /* Para que cargue correctamente en Edge*/ 
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);  /* Para que cargue correctamente en Firefox*/ 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg); /* Para que cargue correctamente en versiones antiguas de Google y Safari, por ejemplo */
    }

#imgDer{
    background-image: url("IMAGENES_ACT1/der_WB.jpg");
    }
    
#imgDer:hover{
    background-image: url("IMAGENES_ACT1/der_redim.jpg");
    transform: rotate(20deg) scale(0.8);    /*Con scale, reduzco el tamaño a un 80%*/
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg) scale(0.8);   /* Para que cargue correctamente en Edge*/ 
    -moz-transform: rotate(20deg) scale(0.8);  /* Para que cargue correctamente en Firefox*/ 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg) scale(0.8); /* Para que cargue correctamente en versiones antiguas de Google y Safari, por ejemplo */
    }

#imgCasa {
    width: 100px;
    height: 86px;
    background-image: url("IMAGENES_ACT1/casa_redim.jpg");
    transition: transform 0.5s ease; /* Se anima el cambio de tamaño */
}   
#imgCasa:hover{
    background-image: url("IMAGENES_ACT1/casa_redim.jpg");
    transform: scale(1.2); /* Aumenta el tamaño al 120% */
}

y este es html con el que estoy trabajando (Actividad_1.html)
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Actividad 1, Unidad 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="UD2_estilos.css"> 
    <!-- <script src="rollover_Act1.js"></script> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="imgIzq"></div>
        <div id="imgCasa"></div>
        <div id="imgDer"></div> <!-- Cada una de las imágenes -->
    </body>
</html>


Esta es una posible solución:
#imgIzq, #imgDer, #imgCasa {
  transition-property: background-image, transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

Explicación:
Es recomendable especificar transition-property en lugar de usar transition: all 1s linear para evitar errores. Especifica la propiedad que quieres lograr.
